# Cypress: read, modify and write a json file with a variable as a name of a field

Tags: json, cypress

I'm wrapping my head around a function that reads, adds fields and writes JSON back to the file in Cypress:

```
writeCounterFile(counterName, c) {
    const filename =  Cypress.env("counterFilePath")
    cy.readFile(filename).then((obj) => {
        obj.counterName = c
        cy.writeFile(filename, obj)
    })
    return c
}
```

I'm passing the field name string in `counterName` argument in the function above trying to get the JSON file content look like:

```
{
   "counter1": NN,
   "counter2": XX,
   "counter3": YY
}
```

But the function results in `{"counterName": YY}` because, aparently, `obj.counterName` doesn't recognise `counterName` as the variable.

Plese, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to add properties to an object, the first with dot notation (`.`) - as you saw what follows the dot is (literally) the property name.

The second is bracket notation where the property name is given in a variable, this is the one you want

```
obj[counterName] = c
```

Ref [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> **Syntax**
>
> object.property
> object['property']

Comment: thank you, @steve-zodiac this is exactly what I was looking for. Also thank you for sharing the ref link!